# How to prove $\liminf\Bbb P(X_nY_n\leq b)\geq\Bbb P(Xy\leq b) $ if $X_n\to X$ in distribution and $Y_n\to y\in\Bbb R$ in probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Take $b\in\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $X_n\to X$ in distribution  and suppose $Y_n\to y$ in probability, where $y$ is a constant. How to prove $$\Bbb P(Xy\leq b) \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}\Bbb P(X_nY_n\leq b)?$$

Honestly I have no clue on how to even start, so hints would be great.

Comment: Slutsky's theorem + the Portmanteau theorem

Comment: @Will I want to use the result I seek to prove Slutsky's theorem, so I cannot use it.

Comment: This is actually false. Counter-example: $X_n=X=1, b=y=1$ and $Y_n=1+\frac 1  n$.